# Conjunctions in subordinate clauses

Tags: verb, clauses

I understand that in a subordinate clause, such as with `weil` the main verb is sent to the end of the sentence. However, if I add a conjunction such as `und` does that clause also have its main verb sent to the end of the sentence?

For example:

> I finde Sport nicht so gut, weil es anstrengend ist und ich bin faul!

or

> I finde Sport nicht so gut, weil es anstrengend ist und ich faul bin!

Comment: Note ("weil" question aside): both sentences contain a mistake. I won't correct them; you can find the mistakes in one the questions below)

Comment: @splattne: In one `of the answers`. And you didn't not correct the question, but rolled back the correction, to tell the truth. So if you would please join the [meta discussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/331/266), and explain, why you think that this is the preferred behaviour.

Comment: @userunknown While I agree that mistakes should be corrected, in this specific case the errors are a sign that the author didn't grasp the concept. Changing that part of the question changes the post too much; also, it wouldn't be fair to the people who alredy answered the question in a certain way.

Comment: @userunknown PS: "weil **es** anstrengend ist" isn't a mistake; "es" can be interpreted as an "unpersönliches Subjekt", and is not related to "Sport".

Comment: @splattne: Was meintest Du dann mit "both sentences contain mistakes"?

Comment: @userunknown ich meinte jeweils den "und ich bin faul"-Teil. Eigentlich ursprünglich auch das mit "es" und "er" (nicht guter Stil), aber streng genommen kein Fehler. Hab jetzt geändert in "Both sentences contain a mistake."

Answer (score 2):

First example is unusual und would mean an addition while second describes the reason.

Comment: +1 because both sentences are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is correct. You would find constructions as in the first sentence in informal spoken language.

Comment: Could you supply examples to support your second statement?

Answer (score 0):

First there are two errors in your sentence:

> **Ich** finde Sport nicht so gut, weil **er** anstrengend ist und ich faul bin!

In German "I" is "ich". The word "er" or "es" is a reference to "Sport" and must be in the gender of "der Sport" (male). So you have to use "er" (male) instead of "es" (neutrum).

The word "und" is a conjuction und combines two parts of a sentence. You can also write the complete sentence:

> Ich finde Sport nicht so gut, weil er anstrengend ist und **weil** ich faul bin!

Here you see, that the leading "weil" forces "bin" to be at the end of the sentence (that's the reason why your first sentence is wrong).  In German you can leave out some words which are only repeated like the second "weil", but the position of "bin" is not changed. So you get the right sentence:

> Ich finde Sport nicht so gut, weil er anstrengend ist und ich faul bin!

If you use a sentence like:

> Ich finde Sport nicht so gut, weil er anstrengend und schlumpfig ist.

this sentence can also be completed to:

> Ich finde Sport nicht so gut, weil er anstrengend **ist** und **weil er** schlumpfig ist.

Here you have the same helping verb (Hilfsverb) "ist" (thats the difference to your sentence) and the same subject "er". The double words "ist", "weil" and "er" can be leaved out.

Remark: write instead "schlumpfig" everything that fits and what you want, it **is absolutly not important for the construction of the sentence**.  The only important thing is that there are **two "ist"** in the German sentence to show how you can leave one out. If you do not know "schlumpfig" have a look on [german Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Schl%C3%BCmpfe_%28Fernsehserie%29).

Comment: Wolltest Du schreiben `ungesund`?

Comment: Ich habe übrigens die Frage korrigiert, bevor ich gesehen habe, dass Du auf diesen Fehler eingehst und ich habe es nicht rückgängig gemacht, weil es m.E. nicht die Frage von Gemrman Student ist. Siehe dazu auch [diese Metadiskussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/331/266) (der inzwischen, zugegeben, schwer zu folgen ist, da viele Antworten Off-topic waren, und der Streit darüber den Inhalt überdeckt).