# Nebensatz, der wie ein Hauptsatz gebildet ist

Tags: sentence-structure

Ein kurzer Auszug von *Mieses Karma* von David Safier:

> Alex blickte Nina an und lächelte. «Ich liebe dich. Nur dich.»
>
> Das versetzte mir einen Stich. Es gibt nun mal Sätze, die gefallen
> einem einfach nicht, wenn sie zu jemand anderem gesagt werden.

Meine Frage geht besonders um den Satz: "...die gefallen einem einfach nicht..." Ich glaube, wir haben in diesem Fall doch einen Nebensatz, obwohl er wie ein Hauptsatz gebildet ist. Normalerweise wäre also die Wortreihenfolge: "die einem einfach nicht gefallen". Ich glaube, ich habe dieses Phänomen mal erfahren, wobei ein Nebensatz, trotz seiner normalen Struktur, mit einem Verb an der zweiten Position geschrieben wird. (Ich glaube, es gibt sogar einen Beitrag dazu auf dieser Site, aber ich kann ihn nicht finden.) Ich frage jedenfalls, was die Wirkung dieser alternativen Struktur auf die Bedeutung, Betonung usw. ist.

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage auf Englisch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5525/1696).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es gibt Relativsätze, die haben tatsächlich V2-Stellung! (sic)

Germanisten nennen diese Form naheliegenderweise *V2-Relativsätze*.

Diese "Bauform" ist schon seit dem Mittelalter nachgewiesen (In [dieser Studie](https://www.slm.uni-hamburg.de/ren/media/pdf/ihden-gastvortrag-v2-rs-2016-01-19.pdf) wurden mittelalterliche (und gegenwartliche) Texte nach solchen Fundstellen untersucht und und bis zu 5% der vorkommenden Relativsätze hatten V2-Stellung).

Anscheinend haben solche Sätze die folgenden Eigenschaften:

- Der Hauptsatz ist relativ informationsarm, die transportierte Information steckt zum großen Teil im Nebensatz
- Typischerweise ist das Verb im Hauptsatz ein sog. *existenzanzeigendes* (z.B. "sein", "haben", "kennen") und damit ziemlich aussagelos
- Der Relativsatz *folgt* dem Hauptsatz (und kann nicht wie ein normaler Relativsatz auch eingeschoben sein)

(Alle diese Merkmale treffen auf deinen Beispielsatz zu)

Beispiele von dort:

> Ich kenne ein Mädchen, das hält sich einen Tiger als Haustier

> In dem Rilke-Seminar ist eine Studentin, die kommt aus Italien und spricht fließend deutsch.

Solche Sätze sind grenzwertig, und könnten bei "scharfer Auslegung" als umgangssprachlich betrachtet werden, trotzdem gibt es sie. Ich würde sie allerdings eher als "Ausnahme von der Regel" betrachten.

Es scheint so zu sein, als ob die V2-Stellung im Nebensatz die Wichtigkeit dieses Nebensatzes für die Aussage hervorhebt.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen Anfänge von Märchen der Gebrüder Grimm, z.B. Rumpelstilzchen: *Es war einmal ein Müller, der war arm, aber er hatte eine schöne Tochter.*